# Example of a regular element in noncommutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, algebras

Whats an example of ring $A$ which is not commutative and contains an element $x\in Z(A)$ such that the left multiplication by $x$ is an injection and $x$ is not a unit?

Comment: @BenMillwood I suppose so. I usually feel bad about posting such simple and short things as answers though, since they're so straightforward. I've moved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=M_2(\Bbb Z)$ be $2\times 2$ matrices over $\Bbb Z$ and let $x=2I$ be twice the identity.

Comment: Perfect, simple and nice!!! 
Thanks Adam :)

Comment: Actually I made an edit, I forgot to mention the important fact that I want $A/(x)$ to be a commutative ring (sorry that was actually the entire reason I posted this question).

Comment: @CSA: that's very much a different question. Maybe revert this one to what it was and just ask a new question.

Comment: Ok I reverted it and the new question is posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/888469/example-of-a-regular-element-with-a-commutative-quotient