# Example of a regular element with a commutative quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

Whats an example of ring $A$ which is not commutative and contains an element $x\in Z(A)$ such that the left multiplication by $x$ is an injection and $x$ is not a unit and $A/(x)$ is *commutative*?

Comment: Perhaps something like $A=\mathbb{Z}[a,b]/\left(ab-ba-2\right)$ where the variables are not commutative? Like, modified Weyl algebra. Then $x=2$ should be such element, I believe $A/(2)\cong \left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\right)[a,b]$ with commutative variables.